# Help with Test Class

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Can you please help me write a test class for my code:

```
public class retrieveOpenSafetyObservations    {
   private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller;
   public List<Safety_Observation__c> getOutbaseSafetyObservation()                      {                                    
  return [SELECT Id, Name, Title__c, Priority__c,   Risk_Factor_Ranking__c,Contractor__c,Status__c 
  FROM Safety_Observation__c WHERE Status__c = 'Open' order by id desc limit 10];       
}
}
```

**this is what I have so far:**

```
@isTest
    public class testRetrieveOpenSafetyObservation{
        static testMethod void testOpenSafetyOb(){
                  Safety_Observation__c SafObse = new Safety_Observation__c(
                  Basic_Risk_Factors__c ='Design',
                  Cause_Category__c = '1 Equipment and Material problems',
                  Cause_Code_Sub_Category__c = '3E other Human Error not specified here',
                  Contractor__c = 'a0fg0000000u09l',
                  Contributing_Factors__c = 'qwert',
                  Customer_Name__c = '001g0000007q9Z9',
                  Description__c  = 'bla bla',
                  Human_Factor_Domain__c = 'Staffing Issue (Workload etc.)',
                  Human_Factors__c = 'Alarms',
                  Performance_Improvment_Factors__c = 'Organisational Change',
                  Priority__c =  'Low',
                  Risk_Factor_Ranking__c = '2',
                  SO_Number_Name__c = 'Test',
                  Status__c = 'Open',
                  Title__c = 'Test'
                  );  
         insert SafObse ;                  
            }   
     }
```

Comment: sorry for the mess here is my solution so far:

Comment: could you specify with which part you have a problem finding the way to write test code ?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please update your question with details about what parts of the test aren't working.

Comment: Its worth making your Answer title a little more specific, such as "Help with writing a Test for a Visualforce Controller"

Answer (score 1):

**Data Isolation.** You have taken the first step in achieving the goal to test your code that is to setup the data it requires. Tests by default do not see data in the org, which enforces best practice to create more self contained test code.

**Invoking your Code and Asserting Results.** What you need to do next is call the logic your attempting to test and assert (test) it did what you expected it to and want to continue expecting to do as you write other parts of the system. You do this using Apex itself. A great starting point to understand this further is the [Testing Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing.htm) section in the documentation. There is also a good example of testing a controller in the Visualforce developers guide [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_controller_error_handling.htm).

In your case, having created your test data, your next steps are this...

1. Create an instance of your controller class
2. Call the method/s you want to test such getOutbaseSafetyObservation
3. Assert (test) the method returns your test data (e.g. check the Id's match)
4. As per the [Best Practices](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_best_practices.htm), you should also write tests that test the negative situations, e.g. no data, or data not of the correct status, return an empty list.

I hope this helps in your journey to writing solid and robust software and that you appreciate its better to read about the practices and learn them, than to simply be given the code you need. That said, if any of this is still not making sense to you having read up a little more on the topic, please do raise a new question with more specifics on what you have tried and what your struggling with and we can help!